# Visual Studio 2017 not auto-completing some XAML tags

Tags: xaml, autocomplete, xamarin.forms, intellisense, visual-studio-2017

I am currently learning about Xamarin.Forms and XAML using Visual Studio 2017. Intellisense seems to be working for XAML files for the most part, but there is at least one tag it doesn't autocomplete, which is `OnPlatform`. And when I manually write the tag, it doesn't autocomplete attributes like `x:TypeArguments`. However, it compiles and runs just fine with the `OnPlatform` element.

Is it normal that Intellisense does not work for a (seemingly random) tag? Are there certain tags that are not auto-completed on purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it normal that Intellisense does not work for a (seemingly random) tag?

YES. Sadly, Intellisense support for XAML is patchy. It has been for as long as it has existed. As far as I can tell it does indeed seem random whether it works or not, like you say. I'm sorry that this probably isn't the answer you were hoping for.

There are some suggestions around getting xaml, Xamarin and Intellisense working together here but your mileage may vary:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/93148/getting-xaml-intellisense-to-work-vs-2017

Comment: Yeah, none of those suggestions worked for me. But it's good to know that it's not just me.